# FFMPEG image overlaying video: crash

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a simple script that overlays a set of images on top of a video:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "basevideo.mov" -loop 1 -i "animation/middle_%2d.png" -filter_complex \
"[1:v]setpts=1.0*PTS[midAnimation]; \
[0:v][midAnimation]overlay=shortest=1[outvideo]" \
-map [outvideo] "out.mov"
```

When the script gets to a certain point, I get an "Error while filtering" message (in bright red), and then it hangs on the last frame (I need to "ctrl-c" a few times to exit).

This doesn't happen on all videos, but enough of them to be annoying.

My environment:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
```

Comment: Try with current git version. There was a bug for a few months with the use of shortest=1.

Comment: @Mulvya, is current git version > 3.3.3 "Hilbert" ?

Comment: Yes, current git version will be newer than any numbered release.

Comment: @Mulvya, it works somewhat better with the latest git version (there is no "Error while filtering", for example!), but it still hangs at the end. The last output line is `frame=  631 fps=8.8 q=29.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:19.26 bitrate= 762.0kbits/s speed=0.27x` with the 'fps' and 'speed' slowly decreasing. I need to <ctrl-c> to exit, but there is a video there for me to see. I am using `version git-2017-08-14-62b7553`

Comment: Try with `ffmpeg-86877-g8e275a7` from https://evermeet.cx/pub/ffmpeg/snapshots/

Comment: @Mulvya, this is an improvement, in that the script above now works. But my more complicated script, where other video snippets are concatenating with the overlaid video, is still not. Perhaps I should start a new thread for this? Note that when I go back to FFmpeg 2.8.12 "Feynman", it works fine (though video quality is poor).

Comment: Yes, start a new Q for the different command. Right now, some of the code that manages input queuing for filters with multiple inputs is being rewritten. But not all the changes are in place. If you get a build from Nov 2016, you should be fine. That's before any of the affected code was in flux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63864/discussion-between-coco-and-mulvya).