# How to avoid being deadlocked between FFMPEG 3.3.5 bug and needed feature?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

A project requires an optional FFMPEG feature available in v3.3.5. A command sample is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i original.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=960x540 \
  -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:540[scaled], \
     [1:v][scaled]overlay=shortest=1:x‌​=(main_w-w)/2:eof_ac‌​tion=endall, \
          format=y‌​uv420p[vid], \
     [vid]dra‌​wtext=fix_bounds=tru‌​e:text='This is a comment':font=bold:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-(text_h*1)-40:borderco‌​lor=black@0.25:borde‌​rw=7[out], \
     [0:a]anull‌​[audio]" \
  -map "[out]" -map "[audio]" test.mp4
```

However this version chokes on a bug introduced in v3.3.3. Some related [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1241200/ffmpeg-image-overlaying-video-hangs) "resolve" the problem by rolling back to FFMPEG v3.2.x, but my project cannot live with a v3.3.

Early feedbacks from [Mulvya](https://superuser.com/users/114058/mulvya) suggest a few issues with this command. Any solution to this seemingly deadlocked situation?

Comment: Which is the needed feature?

Comment: Honestly, I cannot remember from immediate working memory. I just remember we had to use at least 3.3.3. I'll ask around and have a look at the changelog.

Comment: Strictly speaking, one can't answer the question in the title since we don't know what the needed feature is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original command can be modded to

```
ffmpeg -y -i original.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=960x540=d=1 \
  -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:540[scaled]; \
     [1:v][scaled]overlay=x‌​=(main_w-w)/2:eof_ac‌​tion=endall, \
          format=y‌​uv420p, \
          dra‌​wtext=fix_bounds=tru‌​e:text='This is a comment':font=bold:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-(text_h*1)-40:borderco‌​lor=black@0.25:borde‌​rw=7[out]; \
     [0:a]anull‌​[audio]" \
  -map "[out]" -map "[audio]" test.mp4
```

---

Alternatively, this gives the same result,

```
ffmpeg -y -i original.mp4 \
  -vf "scale=-1:540,pad=960:540:(ow-iw)/2,
          dra‌​wtext=fix_bounds=tru‌​e:text='This is a comment':font=bold:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-(text_h*1)-40:borderco‌​lor=black@0.25:borde‌​rw=7"
 test.mp4
```

Notes:

1) Distinct filterchains should be separated by semicolons, not commas. A filterchain is distinct when its set of inputs is not identical to the set of outputs of the previous filter e.g. scale takes in one input and emits one output. overlay takes in two inputs, hence that makes a new filterchain.  Similarly, drawtext single output is not passed onto the anull, so that's a different filterchain. Conversely, if the output of a filter is the same as the input to another filter, they can be separated with a comma and labels aren't required at that junction.

2)I've kept the audio filter anull in the modded command, but it doesn't do anything. It's used for testing by devs.

3) overlay defaults to yuv420p output, so format isn't required.

4) The alternate method is preferable since overlay syncs to the base input and drops frames from the overlay if the framerate of the overlay is higher. May not be noticeable in most cases, though.

Comment: Thank you for your time on this question---highly appreciated, and unexpected. I confirm the two version work well on a test movie.

Just a note on the "verbose" version: I am trying to deal with videos and images, which led me to a complex filter. My poor understanding of the filterchains makes it look bad, but this last comment is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: Note: I had to remove `eof_ac‌​tion=endall` on Linux (not on Mac OS X) to have the first version work.

Comment: Same ffmpeg version?

Comment: Good point: 3.3.5 on Linux (I have to remove the `eof_action`), and 3.4.1 on Mac OS X (it works).

Comment: Oh, that's due to the same bug.

Comment: Good catch. Then should you edit your answer and remove it, or that's supposed to work under some conditions? Thanks again for this whole thread!

Comment: I didn't remove it because ordinarily it won't interfere with the intended operation. Semantically, if one removes it, the instruction to the filter changes to repeating the last frame of the overlay input.